# How to serialize & deserialize user inputs gathered from inside a panel?

Tags: c#, serialization, panel

I'm creating an winforms application, that has the user make inputs in different panels. I already wrote a method to traverse through the panel and get the inputs from the different Controls. Now I need to find a way to serialize these inputs and deserialize them later on, so that all inputs are again in the right Controls (e.g. "Jack" is again in the TextBox "tbName").

I thought of multiple solutions, e.g. creating a list for each panel, which serializes to a .txt with a structure similiar to "tbName=Jack" and so on. But I don't really know how I would deserialize that, without traversing both my panel controls and the list again. Or can I possibly serialize the whole Panel object together with the Child-Controls?

```
//This is the method I use to gather the inputs from the panels.

public IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(Control parentControl)
    {
        foreach (Control child in parentControl.Controls)
            {
                yield return child;
                foreach (Control controlChild in GetControls(child))
                {
                    yield return controlChild;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, both are correct and working, but in the end I figured out my own solution to the problem:
I made a seperate class with all the attributes I needed, just like `@krobelusmeetsyndra` suggested, and made a generic List of the class object i just made. Then I traversed through the controls (with the method from my question), put the data in the List and serialized that data with the XmlSerializer.
Same with deserializing: I made a List of my own object type, then loaded the data from the XML in that list, and then assigned it to the right controls.

Hope that helps everyone with the same question!

Answer (score 0):

It's not advised to serialize the whole form, as it has a lot of information you don't need (and t hat may affect performance). Instead, create a separate class, make it `[Serializable()]`, make all the variables you need to store your information, and serialize that class.

**EDIT:**

Say you have the following form:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // here, you create the serializing and deserializing methods
        public void SerializingInfo()
        {
            // done however you see fit
        }

        public StorageClass DeserializingInfo()
        {
            // also done however you see fit
        }
    }
}
```

Then, add another class to your project, which in my example, is named `StorageClass`.
This will look like:

```
namespace Test
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class StorageClass
    {
        // has all your properties
    }
}
```

Then, whatever you need to storage, you can do so by setting/getting the properties in the `Form1`. When you serialize it, all the properties are serialized together, and you can retrieve it by accessing their getter method in `DeserializeInfo()`.

Comment: But I don't really get how that class should look like? It has to serialize the input, the control the input is in, state of the control, etc. I don't know how I can put these cases in variables of a class. Could you maybe provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

For a LIMITED number of controls, you could simply create Settings in your Project --> Properties for each one:
[image]

Then, in the ApplicationSettings property for your control, click the three dots to the right of PropertyBinding...

[image]

...and select the setting for the Text entry:

[image]

You'll now have this:

[image]

Finally, in the FormClosing() event of the form, save the settings:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```